# Laravel 5 JSON Foreach doesnt work

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I am trying to get data from from foreach loop, and i am pulling that data from database. When I try to "foreach" it says `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

```
@php
$extras = json_decode($product->extras);
@endphp

@foreach($extras as $key)

print_r($key);
@endforeach
```

When i do it on local, it works, but on laravel it won't.

Also, when i write OUTSIDE of foreach

```
{{$extras[0][0]}}
```

it works.. any suggestions?

Comment: `print_r($key);` ?? Did you mean `{{ dd($key) }}`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work with dd too

Comment: You could always return $extras through the controller

Comment: Could it be the missing `true` in the second argument to json_decode() which makes the result an associative array? i.e `json_decode($product->extras, true)`

Comment: you can also use `gettype($extras)` to see if it returns an array, object, or other type so you can know if foreach supports those types, there's possibility that it returns null or boolean value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer.. no logic but works..

```
$extras = json_decode($product->extras);
if (is_array($extras) || is_object($extras)){
    foreach ($extras as $extra){  

    }
}
```

Comment: $product->extras should already be a collection if you are using a Laravel relation.

Answer (score 0):

Return your $extras through the controller

```
public function index()
{
   .......
   $extras = $product->extras;
   return view('yourView', compact('extras'));
}
```

Comment: I want to pull only from row "extras", is this correct? http://prntscr.com/k2erow